# MVC3 Model validation not working on a double

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a problem with yhe validation in MVC, my model has a double property and when I submit 10.30 or anything with "." inside it tells me that "The value '10.30' is not valid for Price".
I did some research and they say that model validation should be Culture invariant, I was thinking that it could be the problem since my browser and server is in french but it should'nt.

Here's my code :

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public virtual ActionResult Edit(AuctionModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //do the work
            }
            return View(model);
        }

public class AuctionModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMandatory")]
        [LocalizedDisplayName("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMandatory")]
        [LocalizedDisplayName("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMandatory")]
        [LocalizedDisplayName("Photo")]
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMandatory")]
        [LocalizedDisplayName("StartDate")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMandatory")]
        [LocalizedDisplayName("Price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried entering `10,30` just to double-check if it's a culture issue?

Comment: Yes and I still have an error : The field Price must be a number.

Comment: When it's with a "." it goes server side and ModelState.IsValid = false and when it's a "," it does'nt go server side, the validation is client-side...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finaly I follow this post from Haacked :

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

And it works like fine.

Here's the code :

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
```

And in the global.ascx :

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the culture in OnActionExecuting.

btw I found another point.

```
public class CultureModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
 {      
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = yourCulture;
        }
}
```

Comment: If I add protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        } I still have the same problem but in Debug I can see that before my CurrentCulture is set to {fr}

Comment: yes. btw. i had the same problem. at the moment when the validators run the culture was not yet initialized and in my case german :-)

Comment: Where do you put the CultureModelBinder? I don't find this solution very clean.

Comment: ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CultureModelBinder();

Comment: in protected void Application_Start() in the global.asax.cs